# Name score test

Tags: c#

My code aims to calculate the name score test but im failing to apply the following rules to get the full score.

rules:

- The first occurrence of a letter awards normal points for that letter.
- The second occurrence of a letter only awards half points rounded up.
- The third occurrence of a letter awards double points.
- Any additional occurrences of a letter award no points.
- If a letter appears twice next to each other in a string then both letters award double the normal points for that letter.

  ```
  namespace NameScoreTest
  {
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  public static class Program
  {
      private static Dictionary<char, int> Letters = new Dictionary<char, int>(){
              {'A', 1}, {'B', 3}, {'C', 3}, {'D', 2}, {'E', 1}, {'F', 4}, {'G', 2}, {'H', 4}, {'I', 1}, {'J', 8}, {'K', 5}, {'L', 1}, {'M', 3 }, {'N', 1}, {'O', 1}, {'P', 3}, {'Q', 10 }, {'R', 1}, {'S', 1}, {'T', 1}, {'U',1}, {'V', 4}, {'W', 4}, {'X', 8}, {'Y', 4}, {'Z', 10}
          };

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          int score = CalculateScore("Thomas");

          Console.WriteLine("Score for name Thomas is " + score);
          Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

          Console.ReadKey();            
      }

      public static int CalculateScore(String input)
      {
          // The score
          int score = 0;



      foreach (char c in input)

      {
          char o = Char.ToUpper(c);

              foreach (var item in Letters)
              {
               // Must apply rules here
                  if(o == item.Key)   
                  {
                      score += item.Value;

                  }
              }
  }


          return score;
      }
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: there are many possible approaches, one involves the addition of a data structure to keep track of the number of occurences of each letter so far, one involves the addition of a function to count occurrences per char and a formula; you can make the whole method a one-liner with LINQ, or have nested loops; which one would you chose to go for? or do you have an idea for an algorithm already and don't know how to express a certain aspect of it in C#?

Comment: There is no point in creating a dictionary to just use it like a list. Get the desired entry with: `if (Letters.TryGetValue(o, out int value)) { score += value; }`. That's much faster than looping.

Comment: It's really not hard to format the tabs and new lines correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For each letter you must store the number of occurrence. To do that you need to create a class containing the value and the occurrence.

```
class LetterInfo
{
    public LetterInfo(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; }
    public int Occurrence{ get; set; }
}
```

Now you can initialize the dictionary with

```
private static Dictionary<char, LetterInfo> Letters = new Dictionary<char, LetterInfo>(){
        ['A'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['B'] = new LetterInfo(3),
        ['C'] = new LetterInfo(3),
        ['D'] = new LetterInfo(2),
        ['E'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['F'] = new LetterInfo(4),
        ['G'] = new LetterInfo(2),
        ['H'] = new LetterInfo(4),
        ['I'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['J'] = new LetterInfo(8),
        ['K'] = new LetterInfo(5),
        ['L'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['M'] = new LetterInfo(3),
        ['N'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['O'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['P'] = new LetterInfo(3),
        ['Q'] = new LetterInfo(10),
        ['R'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['S'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['T'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['U'] = new LetterInfo(1),
        ['V'] = new LetterInfo(4),
        ['W'] = new LetterInfo(4),
        ['X'] = new LetterInfo(8),
        ['Y'] = new LetterInfo(4),
        ['Z'] = new LetterInfo(10)
};
```

Then the logic goes like this

```
int score = 0;
int lastPoints = 0;
char lastLetter = (char)0;
foreach (char c in input) {
    char o = Char.ToUpper(c);
    if (Letters.TryGetValue(o, out var info)) {
        info.Occurrence++; // Keep track of the occurrence.
        if (o == lastLetter) {
            score += -lastPoints + 4 * info.Points; // Subtract points for last letter
                                                    // then add double points for both.
            lastPoints =  2 * info.Points;
        } else {
            switch (info.Occurrence) {
                case 1:
                    lastPoints = info.Points;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    lastPoints = (info.Points + 1) / 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    lastPoints = 2 * info.Points;
                    break;
                default:
                    lastPoints = 0;
                    break;
            }
            score += lastPoints;
        }
        lastLetter = o;
    }
}
```

Note that the code remembers the last letter and the points added to the score for that letter. If the current letter is the same as the last, then the points calculated previously in the last loop for that letter are removed, because the last rule applies for it. Then the double points added for both (i.e. 4 times the normal points).

> Thomas    --> 11
>   Emanuelle --> 14       interesting because you get 3 occurrences of `E` and a double `L`.

---

An alternative way to store points and occurrences is to store them in an array and to use the character code as index. In C# you can perform integer arithmetic on `char`. the index is calculated with `int index = o - 'A';`, i.e., the index for `o == 'A'` is `0`.

```
private static int[] Points = new int[26] { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3,
                                            10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10 };
```

The implementation remains basically the same and we don't need an extra class.

```
int score = 0;
int lastPoints = 0;
char lastLetter = (char)0;
int[] occurrences = new int[26];
foreach (char c in input) {
    char o = Char.ToUpper(c);
    if ('A' <= o  && o <='Z') {
        int index = o - 'A';
        occurrences[index]++;
        int points = Points[index];
        if (o == lastLetter) {
            score += -lastPoints + 4 * points;
            lastPoints = 2 * points;
        } else {
            switch (occurrences[index]) {
                case 1:
                    lastPoints = points;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    lastPoints = (points + 1) / 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    lastPoints = 2 * points;
                    break;
                default:
                    lastPoints = 0;
                    break;
            }
            score += lastPoints;
        }
        lastLetter = o;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another dictionary to save every char with its number of occurrences and then calculate point based it.

```
Dictionary<char, int> Letters2 = new Dictionary<char, int>() ;
foreach (char c in input)
{
    char o = Char.ToUpper(c);
    int countofoccur = input.Split(o).Length - 1;
    Letters2.Add(o, countofoccur);
}
```

Or with linq:

```
Letters2.Add(o, input.Count(x => x == o));
```

and for point maybe not perfect approach but you could use switch statement and score has to be double , add this into end line of previous foreach:

```
double score = 0;
Dictionary<char, double> Letters3 = new  Dictionary<char, double>();
foreach(var c2 in Letters)
{
    if (o == c2.Key)
    {
        switch(countofoccur)
        {
            case 1:
                score = c2.Value;
                Letters3.Add(o, score);
                break;
            case 2:
                score = c2.Value+ (0.5 * c2.Value);
                Letters3.Add(o, score);
                break;

            case 3:
                score = c2.Value + (0.5 * c2.Value) +2*c2.Value;
                Letters3.Add(o, score);
                break;
            default :  
            break;  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, with additional Dictionary to store occurences. I've tested with few examples:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<char, int> Letters = new Dictionary<char, int>(){
            {'A', 1}, {'B', 3}, {'C', 3}, {'D', 2}, {'E', 1}, {'F', 4}, {'G', 2}, {'H', 4}, {'I', 1}, {'J', 8}, {'K', 5}, {'L', 1}, {'M', 3 }, {'N', 1}, {'O', 1}, {'P', 3}, {'Q', 10 }, {'R', 1}, {'S', 1}, {'T', 1}, {'U',1}, {'V', 4}, {'W', 4}, {'X', 8}, {'Y', 4}, {'Z', 10}
        };
    private static Dictionary<char, int> occurences = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    private static char previous = ' ';

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int score = CalculateScore("Thomas");

        Console.WriteLine("Score for name Thomas is " + score);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

        Console.ReadKey();            
    }

    public static int CalculateScore(String input)
    {
     // The score
     int score = 0;
     foreach (char c in input)
     {
        char o = Char.ToUpper(c);

        if (occurences.ContainsKey(o))
        {
           occurences[o] += 1;
           if (occurences[o] == 2)
           {
              if (o == previous)
              {
               score += 3 * letters[o]; //if second letter, than previously was added normal value, thus we add triple value to get to double value for both letters
              }
              else
              {
                  score += (int) Math.Ceiling(1.0 * letters[o] / 2);
              }
           }
           else if (occurences[o] == 3)
            {
               if (o == previous)
               {
                  score -= (int) Math.Ceiling(1.0 * letters[o] / 2); //subtracts previously added score for the letter (half of normal value)
                  score += 4 * letters[o]; //adds double value for 2 letters, thus equals 4
                }
                else
                {
                   score += 2 * letters[o];
                }
            }
            else if (o == previous)
            {
               score += 2 * letters[o];
            }
          }
          else
          {
             occurences[o] = 1;
             score += letters[o];
          }
          previous = o;
          Console.WriteLine(score + " " + o);
       }
       return score;
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant but not all rules are met.. still thanks.. it;s something i can start with cheers

Comment: I tried to cover for all. Can you tell me what you don't see covered?

Comment: if the input is thomasss the total score shoulde 14 but the program is returning 17

Comment: From your rules, case of thomasss would be 16, thoma is 10, and sss would be 6 since it's consecutive occurences of same letter, thus 2 for each letter? Or rule is somewhat different? I'll adjust the answer, but please elaborate, since in rules it states that in that case it's double letter value

Comment: @fernandonicolalde did you manage to complete this? If not, can you answer my previous comment and I'll update the answer, based on your interpretation of the rules

Comment: apologise for such late reply. The code work as expected cheers!